# Mongoose: how do you validate that at least one of the following fields is present?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

This is my User schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  role: String,
  auth: {
    hashedPassword: { type: String, select: false },
    facebookToken: { type: String, select: false },
    twitterToken: { type: String, select: false },
    googleToken: { type: String, select: false }
  },
});
```

I want to validate that at least one of the `auth` properties are present. How would I do that?

In looking at the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) for custom validation, it seems that you could only add custom validators on a given field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a [nested schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#required-validators-on-nested-objects) here.

```
const authSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    hashedPassword: { type: String, select: false },
    facebookToken: { type: String, select: false },
    twitterToken: { type: String, select: false },
    googleToken: { type: String, select: false }
  });
```

Which you can use in your main schema:

```
  const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    role: String,
    auth: {
      type: authSchema,
      required: true,
      validate: {
        validator: function(s) {
          const MIN_LENGTH = 6;
          return (
            this.auth.hashedPassword.length >= MIN_LENGTH ||
            this.auth.facebookToken.length >= MIN_LENGTH ||
            this.auth.twitterToken.length >= MIN_LENGTH ||
            this.auth.googleToken.length >= MIN_LENGTH
          );
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

but that's not enough.  As you probably already know, validation isn't run on properties which have not been assigned a value.  So, when I tried to do a similar thing on a POST endpoint recently, I added code to assign empty string values for all the properties that I wanted to force to be validated.

So, in an Express endpoint, for instance, you might do something like:

```
const postUser = async (req, res) => {
  const postedUser = req.body;
  let userObj = Object.assign({}, postedUser);
  userObj.auth.hashedPassword = userObj.auth.hashedPassword || "";
  userObj.auth.facebookToken = userObj.auth.facebookToken || "";
  userObj.auth.twitterToken = userObj.auth.twitterToken || "";
  userObj.auth.googleToken = userObj.auth.googleToken || "";
```

..before you validate your model.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
var user = require('./path/to/userSchema');

var detectAuthMethod = function(userName, callback){
  user.findOne(username: username, function(err, doc){ // Finds user by userName string. userName is required.
    if(err) throw err;
    for (var key in doc.auth){ // Iterates through all doc.auth keys
      if (doc.auth.hasOwnProperty(key){ // Checks if they key has been set
        callback(null, key); // Callback "return". Status succes (null), and response is they setted key.
      }
    }
  callback('err, there is no valid key.'); // Callback "return". Status is an error message, and there is no response key.
  });
}
```

And then you could call the function from the source file like this:

```
detectAuthMethod('bob', function(err, key){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Bob has been authenticated with %s key', key);
});
```

If you need to call the function from somewhere else (instead of the source file), adding this at the end of the source file should be enough:

```
module.exports.detectAuthMethod = detectAuthMethod;
```

And then require the source file from somewhere else and use it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was wondering like me you can validate like this

```
const schema = new Schema({
  a: String,
  b: {
    type: String,
    required: function() { return this.a === 'test'; } // Only required if a equals 'test'
  }
});
```